# How to remove newly created directory not part of rpm package

Tags: shell, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, rpm-spec

I am new to rpm creation. I need to find a way to install/uninstall/upgrade a plugin in jenkins using rpm.I am able to install plugin using rpm , but on un-installation how can I delete new file/directory which was not part of the package.

Suppose my package only deploys xyz.jpi file on server which on server restart creates xyz.jpi and xyz folder . On uninstallation I want to remove both created folders .

Comment: `rpm` (un)installation shouldn't remove file not owned by the package. In your case, `xyz` folder should be owned by that `rpm`.

Comment: Only directories and file which are packaged in rpm/ created by it are only liable to deleted when you uninstall. Rest either you delete manually or write a uninstallation script which gets track of all other paths which needs to be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the `%ghost` directive in the `%files` section; which means "this file/folder does not exist yet, but when it appears it will be mine."

```
%files
%ghost %dir /path/to/unexisting/xyz
```

If there will be files present in that directory; I am not sure rpm will remove them. In that case it might be necessary to add another line (to be tested!)

```
%ghost /path/to/unexisting/xyz/*
```

more information in the [documentation](http://ftp.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-inside-files-list-directives.html)

Answer (score 0):

How about in `%postun` section check if this is the last instance of the package who owns this folder.

E.g:
In our case all products (a,b,c) co-own `/opt/xy`z then the last of a, b, c on its uninstall remove the `/opt/xyz` folder (if it is not installed by rpm).

we are checking this by `rpm -qa | egrep 'b|c'` ....
if nothing present then we do `rm -rf /opt/xyz`